# Is "regularly updated about a couple of dozen minutes" phrased correctly?

Tags: grammaticality

Am I saying this well?

I just want to say:

> regularly updated about ~2x-3x-4x 12 minutes.

I have a script that updates a website between ~0-40 minutes time interval.
I just want to write it on the website at what time intervals it's regularly updated. I don't want to be exact, that's why I don't want to write ~0-40 minutes.

Comment: can you provide a bit more context, please? Is the object updated only after increments of 12 minutes, so either 24, 36 or 48 minutes?

Comment: ok, I updated it!

Comment: _Updateded_ doesn't exist. "Updated" is _already_ a past participle, from the verb **to update**.

Comment: In addition to what @Alenanno says, it's *regularly*, with a *-ly*.

Comment: @RegDwight: Ah, I didn't notice that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A dozen minutes" isn't a commonly used unit of time.

How about saying:

> This page is updated up to 5 times an hour.

Answer (score 3):

To state the frequency of the updates, I would simply say *“updated **every** 12 minutes”* (if you want to specify the exact interval), or *“updated **at least** every 40 minutes”* (to give an upper bound).

As others have stated, *updated* is the past participle of *update*, and *updateded* does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, in the end, there aren't many ways to say that message.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the phrase

> “regularly updated about a couple of dozen minutes”

It seems like the idea you are trying to convey is that the website is updated every ~24 minutes or so. 
Given that, I would use something like

> This is updated at regular intervals of 24 minutes.